# auto fill home address in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, autofill

Can iOS auto-fill a user's home address similar to how you can do in HTML5?

I've looked at UIWebView and UITextfield, but don't see any requests to retrieve the user's address (like when you request to gain access to their photos, camera, etc..)

Comment: How would iOS know what your home address is? Do you mean just autofill like desktop Safari for previous entered data into a form eg. register/login?

Comment: yes like how on desktop you can fill in your previously filled address